# Fit a cosine squared function to a set of data

Tags: python, optimization, graph, physics, curve-fitting

I took a set of data from an experimental set up and am trying to model an interference pattern for a diffraction grating. Currently my function does not overlay itself well onto the data and was wondering whether there is a way to improve the fitting.

[EDIT] From the comments I have received I am now trying to fit the sin(x)**2 function onto the graph, where in this case amplitude is a position of another/several functions, or fit a superposition of sine waves. Additionally whilst trying to overlay a Gaussian distribution over the peaks of the data points see image 2

```
import scipy as sp
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

x=sp.array([5.5,5.75,5.95,6,6.1,6.2,6.2,6.4,6.5,6.75,7,7.05,7.1,7.15,7.2,
7.3,7.35,7.5,7.55,7.7,8,8.2,8.3,8.35,8.4,8.6,8.7])

V=sp.array([0.048,0.1,0.617,0.557,0.258,0.112,0.098,0.08,0.075,0.093,0.253,
0.486,0.98,1.391,1.58,0.964,0.71,0.166,0.152,0.11,0.121,0.256,0.591,1.186,
1.552,0.787,0.283])

def my_sin(t,peroid,amplitude,phase):
           return (amplitude*(sp.sin(t*2*sp.pi/peroid+phase)))**2

guess_peroid= 2
guess_amplitude = 0.8
guess_phase = (sp.pi)/2

p0 =[guess_peroid, guess_amplitude, guess_phase]
fit = curve_fit(my_sin,x, V, p0=p0)
print ('The fit paramters are:', fit[0])
x1 = sp.linspace(5.5,8.7,100000)
data_fit = my_sin(x1,*fit[0])

print(x1)
plt.xlabel('Distance Between Minima(m)')
plt.ylabel('Voltage')
plt.plot(x1,data_fit)
plt.errorbar(x,V,fmt='x')
plt.show()
```

[Here is a picture of the output of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GRon.png)

[I would like to replicate this kind of fitting for the three Maxima of Light Intensity shown in my data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8Slp.gif)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[An Image of the formula i am using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGy8D.png)

Comment: Please include the image rather than link to it.

Comment: Your amplitude is the same for all sines (squared). You should make the amplitude a function of (an)other parameter(s), and fit that instead of the amplitude. This based on the assumption that your example image is representative of the actual data you're trying to fit.

Comment: the image you would like to replicate looks nothing like sin(x)^2.   I believe @Evert is suggesting some envelope function (say, Gaussian) times sin(x)^2, which might work.  I wonder if you might instead want a sum of sin(x)^2 with different frequencies and amplitudes.   Either way, I think you need a better model function for the physics you're modeling.

Comment: It appears you want to fit the maximum values of each peak to a function, and that most of the raw data is not strictly necessary for your purpose. Is this correct?

Comment: @MNewville could you point me in the direction of either creating a superposition of sin(x)^2 with different frequencies and amplitudes or create an envelope function in the form a normal distribution

Comment: @JamesPhillips  In my code I was trying to fit the data so that it moved from pick to trough and back to the next peak again

Comment: @Evert Using this approach how many parameters would I need to potentially fit the three peaks in this graph. And how would I go about incorporating these into my code

Comment: @JamesPhillip however i would like to try to overlay a normal distribution along that moves through the peaks and encloses the curve in a bell shape

Comment: Despite the fact that this is a programming site, let me make some comments on physics: Why do you fit a grating with `sin()**2`. You should get the formula for gratings. Is it mono chromatic light? What do you try to figure out single slit width to grating width? Wavelength?

Comment: @mikuszefski I was measuring the distance between successive minima. A laser was focused through  coarse diffraction grating onto a focal lens and onto a photodiode. So that for intents and purposes the voltage was equal to intensity as a function of there. From this point I used the formula initial intensity*((sin(x)**2)/x)*cosx where x is a made of four constants pi, lambda, slit separation and distance. After collecting data points of note I.e troughs and peaks. I decided it would be useful to plot the graph as seen in image 2 to determine slit separation by using the formula above.

Comment: Hmmm, the positions of the minima in a grating diffraction are not well defined and your graph (where I cannot read the x-scale...but you put the data) seems to be voltage vs position. The formula you give looks like a double slit with some squares missing.

Comment: @mikuszefski, hi yes you are correct, i seem to have accidental cutoff the positions on the x axis, I have edited my original post with the formula that I am adopting for this investigation

Comment: As I said, this is a double slit formula, not grating. And you have intensity as function of position. As I do not know the geometry of your setup, you need to transform this into angle. (Maybe you also have a look [here](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwju9d-x26LZAhXoCMAKHcUVCewQFggpMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fweb.mit.edu%2Fviz%2FEM%2Fvisualizations%2Fcoursenotes%2Fmodules%2Fguide14.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3elcBmXXoRFj_jCBYPVWvJ)) ...and the wavelength? HeNe-Laser od diode?

Comment: Simply adding a gaussian function, because it looks good, is not the way to go. It is a common mistake to take a fit function, impose it on the data and say "See, fits well.". In your case, you know the underlying mechanism. @mikuszefski was kind enough to guide you. Now you have to implement this. You know your parameters. We don't.

Comment: @mikuszefski thank you for the document i have just finished reading it. I used a red helium neon laser of 637nm and a focal lens of 500mm focused onto a photodiode. I was wondering how I could convert my positions into angles. would i use Xm = (order*frequency*lambda)/distance

Comment: Well, I guess your setup is somewhat to Fig 14.6.1 in the link above, only with a grating instead of a single slit. Probably your *x*-values are either the position of the lens and/or the diode. So from your distance *d* and position *x* you need to get that *theta* in the intensity formula for gratings `( sin( N pi a / lambda sin( theta ) ) / sin( pi a / lambda sin( theta ) ) )**2`...and you have to multiply with the single slit intensity. If your *d* is much larger than *x* `sin(  theta ) = x/d = kappa` otherwise it is `kappa / sqrt( 1 + kappa**2 )` (check `sin( arctan( y ) )` )

Comment: [This](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=13&ved=0ahUKEwjJv5O1kaXZAhXHYlAKHZZpAEYQFgh9MAw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.physnet.uni-hamburg.de%2FTUHH%2FVersuchsanleitung_eng%2FBeugung_am_Spalt_eng.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0FxD0gXnypZ4fUZyv1ISoh) might also help a little.